# off topic sobre pontuação e outras coisas mais

Tags: debate, suporte

1) O que leva uma pergunta a receber pontos negativos?

2) Não consigo fazer logout do site

3) Porque depois que uma pergunta recebe algumas respostas, mesmo se a resposta não satisfaz ainda ao perguntador, ou seja, não respondeu a questão, ela não mais recebe novas respostas e/ou comentários?

Comment: Mais uma coisa, você está levantando vários assuntos diferentes em uma só pergunta. Lembre-se que você não tem limite para perguntar, portanto crie perguntas separadas para cada uma delas.

Comment: Pois sim, vc tem [uma bela coleção de perguntas <= -1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6420/pnet?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=2)...

Comment: Você tem 4 perguntas aqui no Meta, 3 delas foram migradas do SOPT para cá. Ainda não está claro para você qual pergunta é apropriada para qual site?

Comment: Putz!! Não acerto uma aqui, rs. Sempre censurada ou negativada. Deixa quieto e vou me concentrar em minha dúvidas de c# mesmo e mvc e javascript e web service e etc..

Comment: O que é SOPT e META

Comment: SOPT é [StackOverflow em PorTuguês](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/), e [META](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) é este aqui, que serve para discutir problemas do SOPT em si.

Comment: Não se esqueça que aqui não tem funcionários onde você manda e todos obedecem. Você quer que seus posts sejam levados em consideração, dê consideração para eles. Se você passar o mouse em cima da seta para baixo verá que ela serve para votar em posts de baixa qualidade ou que não tem utilidade. Seus posts mostram pouco esforço na maioria dos casos. É comum suas perguntas pedirem o peixe e não como pescar. É comum ver que todo mundo está fazendo o seu trabalho para você. A sugestão é que estude mais, aprenda como achar erros, não tenha pressa, mostre esforço na pergunta. Tudo vai mudar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Acredito que Alguns motivos para uma pergunta levar downvote são:

- Descrição vaga do problema e nenhuma atitude em melhora-la.
- Pergunta fora do formato do site.
- Muito desleixo na formatação.
- O autor não demonstrou nenhum esforço para
  resolver o problema, parece que está pedindo que alguém faça o seu
  trabalho.

Apesar de um pouco antigo e agressivo vale apena a leitura de [como fazer perguntas inteligentes](http://www.fabrica10.com.br/projetos/comofazerperguntasinteligentes.html)

Um dos objetivos do site é gerar um base de conhecimento sobre programação e afins em português ou seja o stackoverflow não é um helpdesk. 
As pessoas que respondem são todas voluntarias não ganham dinheiro nenhum por isso. Se não conseguir uma resposta adequada ao seu problema
talvez precise descrever melhor os detalhes e quais **abordagens já tentou**. Tente descrever melhor o problema, quem responde não tem a mesma 
visão que você. Então evite resumir os *sintomas* do código em: não funcionou, não deu certo. descreva!

Comment: Valeu perdeu. Eu sei, às vezes na pressa de uma resposta, querendo ajudar, acabamos nos prejudicando mesmo, com perguntas não claras. Aceito sua resposta como uma puta orientação em como fazer certo, um blue print. Valeu.

Comment: @pnet, leia o link ele da uma boa ideia de como refinar perguntas.

Comment: @pnet pela aceitação da resposta, parece que você é bem intencionado e entendeu o recado. Acho que vai melhorar agora e vai colher bons resultados no site.

Answer (score 16):

Analisando algumas das suas perguntas com menor pontuação:

### [Dúvida de lambda em um tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12917/duvida-de-lambda-em-um-tipo)

- Se um programa não compila por causa de um erro de sintaxe na linguagem, isso demonstra falta de interesse em resolver o problema, é como se você estivesse dizendo assim: "programem isso para mim"
- Em um dos comentários, você colocou código sem o tal erro de sintaxe... você deveria ter editado a questão. Foi uma oportunidade perdida de melhorá-la.
- Parece que você se contentou em levar down-votes... quando eu levo down-vote sem explicação, eu reviso várias vezes o texto, verifico se não tem algo incoerente, se não tiver nada de errado, eu coloco um comentário questionando o down-vote. Isso mostra que você está empenhado em melhorar.
- **Recomendação:** editar a questão permite que o down-voter retire o voto negativo, caso a edição tenha sanado os problemas.

### [Mostrar informação quando não há dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11500/mostrar-informacao-quando-nao-ha-dados)

- O título é contraditório e incompleto. Eu não dou down-vote por isso, mas há quem o faça. Informação não seria algo que se fundamenta em dados? Então como é possível? Um título melhor seria: "Como mostrar mensagem quando não há dados no view-model?"
- Você tenta descrever o código com palavras, quando o próprio código seria muito mais explicativo... ao invés de "Fiz um `If`... que se comporta assim, e assado...", teria sido melhor colocar o código... retirando somente as partes irrelevantes ao problema.
- Falta informação: várias pessoas pediram que postasse mais informações sobre o problema, mas você não editou a questão nem uma única vez.
- Você não aceitou a resposta que resolveu seu problema, isso é ruim, pois as pessoas agora já olham suas questões com certa desconfiança. Isso explica o seu ponto (3).
- **Recomendação 1:** dê satisfações... editar a questão de forma a satisfazer aqueles que estão se esforçando para tentar te ajudar, ou pelo menos, deixar um comentário explicando o motivo pelo qual a apresentação dessas novas informações seria irrelevante, contraprodutiva ou impossível (existem casos, em que há de se manter segredo sobre o código, e.g. código fechado).
- **Recomendação 2:** aceitar uma resposta caso ela seja a que resolveu o seu problema.

### https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13717/estou-tendo-dificuldades-de-fazer-uma-imagem-com-alguns-checkboxes-e-mostrar-no

- A questão toda é praticamente uma imagem, sem demonstrar nenhuma tentativa de tentar fazer algo. Se as pessoas sentirem que você está querendo que elas programem para você, então provavelmente terá down-votes.
- Está mal explicado: como assim colocar check-boxes em uma imagem? Não seria colocar check-boxes sobre uma imagem? Ou seria, renderizar check-boxes na própria imagem?
- **Recomendação:** tente resolver o problema antes de submeter uma questão, e mostre de que formas você tentou resolver o problema.

### [Quando carrego a classe na view, dá erro de NullException](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12495/quando-carrego-a-classe-na-view-da-erro-de-nullexception)

- Você não respondeu as perguntas feitas nos comentários. Até hoje não se sabe se o `SessaoUtil` é estático ou não.
- Problemas com `NullReferenceException` são geralmente por falta de atenção... é um erro muito fácil de corrigir, então é necessário que a questão seja muito bem trabalhada, e que você mostre que já testou de várias formas sem sucesso... já fez busca binária pelo erro, etc.. é necessário demonstrar muito esforço no caso de exceções banais.
- Sua resposta à sua própria pergunta, contém muita informação desnecessária... de forma que fica difícil dizer se esta sua questão/resposta algum dia poderá ser útil para outras pessoas... me impressiona a resposta não ter sido negativada também.
- **Recomendação 1:** responda aos usuários que estão tentando te ajudar.
- **Recomendação 2:** faça uma resposta concisa direto ao ponto... ou que pelo menos que seja facilmente destacável de todo o resto, que no caso é off-topic.
- **Recomendação 3:** tente resolver o problema antes de submeter uma questão, e se o problema for genérico demais, ou uma exceção que normalmente é banal... ai mesmo que você deve duplicar o esforço despendido.

### [Como colocar pontinho ou marcadores de localização no mapa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/como-colocar-pontinho-ou-marcadores-de-localizacao-no-mapa)

- A questão está muito pobre de informações... a interpretação que eu tive ao ver a postagem inicial foi: "o cara quer uma resposta completa com um exemplo que funcione out-of-the-box", ou seja, quer que programem para ele.
- **Recomendação:** trabalhe melhor a questão antes de postar... você só postou o javascript 3 horas depois da postagem inicial. Total falta de atenção.

### [off topic sobre pontuação e outras coisas mais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248/off-topic-sobre-pontuacao-e-outras-coisas-mais)

- Muitas perguntas em uma só questão
- Questão foi feita inicialmente no lugar errado
- **Recomendação 1:** Poste as questões nos sites corretos:

  - SOPT: questões sobre programação, ou relacionadas
  - Meta: questões sobre o site e comunidade do SOPT em si
- **Recomendação 2:** Não faça uma avalanche de questões não relacionadas na mesma postagem. Divida

### [Associar uma controller a uma view já existente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9129/associar-uma-controller-a-uma-view-ja-existente)

- Postagem inicial mal formatada... fica difícil ler sem ter uma formatação. Depois que o Cigano formatou ficou muito mais legível... ele te ajudou a não ganhar mais down-votes.
- Nenhuma resposta aceita... isso te prejudica demais.
- Você postou uma resposta que não era resposta.
- Não entendi o down-vote... realmente, até que faz sentido ter o caminho inverso de criar uma Action a partir de uma view. Até dei um upvote agora!
- **Recomendação:** Marque uma resposta correta, ou então poste a solução que você adotou, para ajudar a outras pessoas no futuro.

### https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11150/loop-no-jquery-nao-monta-html-na-cshtml

- Baixa qualidade da questão... você se resume a dizer que não funciona, como deveria funcionar e postar um código. Ou seja, programem para mim.
- **Recomendação:** Edite a questão de forma que se torne mais atrativa, assim reverterá os down-votes.

Comment: Devia ter com dar mais de um voto, pela qualidade e pela paciência.

Comment: Ok, realmente estou me adaptando ao site e acho que esse é o caminho. Não vou aqui ficar debatendo, principalmente quando estou errado na maioria das vezes. Alguns desses posts(2) eu não continuei mais na empresa. Mudei de empresa e estou em outra agora. Talvez faltou dar essa satisfação a vocês. Recebo do Miguel a informação, como um aprendizado em relação ao Site. Posso garantir que nunca quis que ninguém fizesse por mim, apesar das aparências. Logo preciso mudar a forma de utilizar o site. Agradeço a todos pela ajuda. Tenho votado sim nas respostas mais significativas. Valeu!!

Comment: @pnet: gostaria de frisar que ainda é possível reverter vários desses problemas... não é tarde para rever algumas dessas questões e melhorá-las.

Comment: Pois é, esta resposta merecia no mínimo uma recompensa (pena que isso não existe no Meta). @pnet, essa análise de vários posts é um tremendo presente que o Miguel te deu, que sorte :)

Comment: @pnet: sobre você não estar conseguindo fazer logout do site... eu não sei te responder. Creio que seja melhor você abrir uma nova questão (aqui no Meta)